# How do I open NetBeans HMTL context menu?

Tags: netbeans, contextmenu

I'm creating a simple HTML webpage and, I don't know how, I opened a context menu that has many graphic items like buttons, checkboxes and so.

How do I open that context menu? It seems like a simpler way to create a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `Window / IDE Tools / Palette` (Ctrl + Shift + 8)?

Comment: Yes, but to me appeared as when you make a right click, I don't know how. Any way, thanks, this help me too.